# How to use quoted type annotations for base class in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, type-hinting

Suppose I want to create a class like this:

```py
class foo(dict[str, str]):
  pass
```

Pyright correctly highlights that the `[]` subscript will cause a runtime error:

```
Python 3.8.7 (default, Jan  9 2021, 01:55:12) 
[Clang 9.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class foo(dict[str, str]):
...   pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

This is fixed in Python 3.9, but unfortunately I am stuck on Python 3.8. The normal solution to this for parameters is to add quotes around the type, like this:

```py
x: "dict[str, str]" = ...
```

But I can't figure out how to do that with a base class. Neither of these work:

```py
class foo("dict[str, str]"):
  pass

class foo(dict: "dict[str, str]"):
  pass
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, those won't work. The base class must be an actual type, and it cannot be annotated with the `:` syntax.

In Python 3.8 you should just use the types from the `typing` module:

```
from typing import Dict

class foo(Dict[str, str]):
    pass
```

Comment: Ah that works! So what's the difference between `Dict` and `dict`? And why does it choke on `dict[` but not `Dict[`? The Python documentation doesn't explain it at all.

Comment: `typing.Dict` is simply `dict` which allows specifying generic types with the `[]` syntax. Its signature is `class typing.Dict(dict, MutableMapping[KT, VT])` https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Dict

Comment: With Python 3.10 you no longer have to use `Dict` or `List` from `typing`, just use regular `dict` or `list`